# jQuery to serialize only elements within a div

Tags: jquery, serialization

I would like to get the same effect as `jQuery.serialize()` but I would like to return only the child elments of a given `div`.

**Sample result :**

```
single=Single2&multiple=Multiple&radio=radio1
```

Answer (score 299, accepted):

No problem. Just use the following. This will behave exactly like serializing a form but using a div's content instead.

```
$('#divId :input').serialize();
```

Check https://jsbin.com/xabureladi/1 for a demonstration (https://jsbin.com/xabureladi/1/edit for the code)

Comment: Wouldn't `$("#divId").find("select, textarea, input").serialize();` yeild better performance? I imagine the above could get slow if the div had lots of elements, like a table with several rows/columns.

Comment: As listed in other answers, $('#divId :input').serialize() would be more efficient.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch it's indeed faster: http://jsfiddle.net/QAKjN/ see console: difference is 4ms

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses that's not a very accurate way to test. If you switch the order of the statements you'll notice that there isn't really any difference: http://jsfiddle.net/QAKjN/10/. There's more in play than the selectors

Comment: Clearly this also only serializes inputs, so David Murdochs comment would be the right way to do it.

Comment: jQuery: "Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method." using $('[name]') will be better: document.querySelectorAll('[name]');

Comment: this does not look to be working with jquery 1.11.1 it returns empty string if i use serialize with the current selector `$("#divId :input")` , although if i remove the serialize method , it returns all the input elements inside the div thou , any idea why

Comment: it isnt working with the latest version too, strange

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam That's because someone tought it's a great idea to change the link from my solution to something which doesn't even work. Changed back to working jsbin link

Answer (score 23):

You can improve the speed of your code if you restrict the items jQuery will look at.

Use the selector **:input** instead of ***** to achieve it.

```
$('#divId :input').serialize()
```

This will make your code faster because the list of items is shorter.

Answer (score 15):

#### `serialize` all the form-elements within a `div`.

You could do that by targeting the div `#target-div-id` inside your `form` using :

```
$('#target-div-id').find('select, textarea, input').serialize();
```

Answer (score 5):

The function I use currently:

```
/**
 * Serializes form or any other element with jQuery.serialize
 * @param el
 */
serialize: function(el) {
    var serialized = $(el).serialize();
    if (!serialized) // not a form
        serialized = $(el).
          find('input[name],select[name],textarea[name]').serialize();
    return serialized;
}
```

Comment: Also .find('[name]').serialize(); can be used to filter 'serializable' elements.

Answer (score 3):

Try also this:

> $('#divId').find('input').serialize()

Comment: This will not serialize select elements and textareas in the div

Comment: This corrects the select and textarea issue: <code>$("#divId").find("select, textarea, input").serialize(); <//code>

Answer (score 2):

What about my solution:

```
function serializeDiv( $div, serialize_method )
{
    // Accepts 'serialize', 'serializeArray'; Implicit 'serialize'
    serialize_method = serialize_method || 'serialize';

    // Unique selector for wrapper forms
    var inner_wrapper_class = 'any_unique_class_for_wrapped_content';

    // Wrap content with a form
    $div.wrapInner( "<form class='"+inner_wrapper_class+"'></form>" );

    // Serialize inputs
    var result = $('.'+inner_wrapper_class, $div)[serialize_method]();

    // Eliminate newly created form
    $('.script_wrap_inner_div_form', $div).contents().unwrap();

    // Return result
    return result;
}

/* USE: */

// For: $('#div').serialize()
serializeDiv($('#div')); /* or */ serializeDiv($('#div'), 'serialize');

// For: $('#div').serializeArray()
serializeDiv($('#div'), 'serializeArray');
```

```js
function serializeDiv( $div, serialize_method )
{
 // Accepts 'serialize', 'serializeArray'; Implicit 'serialize'
 serialize_method = serialize_method || 'serialize';

 // Unique selector for wrapper forms
 var inner_wrapper_class = 'any_unique_class_for_wrapped_content';

 // Wrap content with a form
 $div.wrapInner( "<form class='"+inner_wrapper_class+"'></form>" );

 // Serialize inputs
 var result = $('.'+inner_wrapper_class, $div)[serialize_method]();

 // Eliminate newly created form
 $('.script_wrap_inner_div_form', $div).contents().unwrap();

 // Return result
 return result;
}

/* USE: */

var r = serializeDiv($('#div')); /* or serializeDiv($('#div'), 'serialize'); */
console.log("For: $('#div').serialize()");
console.log(r);

var r = serializeDiv($('#div'), 'serializeArray');
console.log("For: $('#div').serializeArray()");
console.log(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
  <input name="input1" value="input1_value">
  <textarea name="textarea1">textarea_value</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divId > input, #divId > select, #divId > textarea').serialize();
```

Comment: If comma is used, then you need to specify the `ID` in each selector, like: `$('#divId > input, #divId > select, #divId > textarea')`; Also, the `>` symbol it refers to direct children elements... Very unusual in this scenario or at least, very restrictive .

Answer (score 0):

If those elements have a common class name, one may also use this:

```
$('#your_div .your_classname').serialize()
```

This way you can avoid selection of buttons, which will be selected using the jQuery selector `:input`. Though this can also be avoided by using `$('#your_div :input:not(:button)').serialize();`