# serialize without a form?

Tags: jquery, serialization, object

Hello all i'm turning objects "on (adding the class .active) and off" on a html page with html objects, not forms. And on every click i want it to create an array of the items with the class .active but i can't seem to get any results?!

is this in the right direction?

```
var data = $('li.tagToggle.active').serializeArray();
// li id format is 'id_0001' 
alert(data)
$.post("/scripts/php/process.php",{ 
         'data[]': data,
         funcName : 'tagResults',
         tagResults : '1'
})
```

keeps alerting and empty window but when i use this on a form it grabs all the objects with the class .active

any pointers welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok - got this to work but its nots as neat as serialize()

```
function getTags(){

    var data = [];

    $('li.tagToggle.active').each(function(){
        var me = $(this);
        var id = me.attr("id").split('_');
        data.push(id[1])

    });

    $.post("/scripts/php/process.php",{ 
         'data': data,
         funcName : 'tagResults',
         tagResults : '1'
    }) 

}
```

think there's a better method?

Comment: I like it.  data.push is a nice solution to building the object, and being able to merge it with other data that you might have for submitting.

Answer (score 24):

You can serialize all inputs inside an element like this:

```
var data = $('YourId :input').serialize()
```

Comment: Colon is in the wrong place. Should be var data = $('YourId :input').serialize()

Answer (score 9):

This is what I'm using

```
(function($){
$.fn.serializeAny = function() {
    var ret = [];
    $.each( $(this).find(':input'), function() {
        ret.push( encodeURIComponent(this.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( $(this).val() ) );
    });

    return ret.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");
}
})(jQuery);
```

to use it in your case
**$('li.tagToggle.active').serializeAny();**

Comment: This isn't a good answer. You aren't checking if an element has name of if it's a button or if it's a checked checkbox or radio. `.serializeArray` also checks if an element is disabled. Also you could use `$.param` for parameterizing your array.

Comment: One could easily add IF condition to suffice whatever he needs. even if the element is disabled you ought to still send it to server. Finally if its checkbox or radio, the .val() should still handle it

Comment: But also sends value when it is unchecked, so it IS working wrong. OP was interested in an effect of `.serialize` on other elements than forms, so the more similar to `.serialize` the better. Your function does almost no filters and checks in comparison to what jQuery does with its `.serializeArray` and you add boilerplate, which could and should be handled by `$.param`. It only looks somewhat complicated, what could fool beginners into thinking about it as something safe. Well, it isn't safe. That's why I downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 7):

With this function you can make any set of elements serializable:

```
function makeSerializable(elem) {
  return $(elem).prop('elements', $('*', elem).andSelf().get());
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var arr = makeSerializable('li.tagToggle.active').serializeArray();
```

or

```
var $elem = $('li.tagToggle.active');
var data = makeSerializable($elem).serialize();
```

Answer (score 3):

in case somebody stumble upon this question, this link is same question and the solution is using jquery serialize

```
    $('#divId :input').serialize();
```

so in this case

```
    $('li.tagToggle.active :input').serialize();
```

link to question [jQuery to serialize only elements within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829519/jquery-to-serialize-only-elements-within-a-div)