# serialize from a table element and not the whole form

Tags: jquery, serialization

Trying to serialize just the elements from a specific table but it only returns a result if i do the whole `Form`

in the below code, i want to ajax just the elements in tbl2

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="tb1" name="tbl1"/>
  <table name="tbl1">
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="tb2"/></td></tr>
 </table>
 <table name="tbl2">
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="tb3"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="tb4"/></td></tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

the code

```
var params = $("#tbl2").serialize();

var resp = $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: AppRoot + "webhandlers/postback.ashx",
    data: params
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First and foremost, a `<table>` cannot have a `name` attribute, and even if it could, the [jQuery ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (`#`) would not match it.

If you use `id` instead (`<table id="tbl2">`), it will work like this:

```
var params = $("#tbl2 :input").serialize();
```

The `:input` selector selects all the form elements (here, inside `#tbl2`), it is needed because `serialize()` will only work on those.

Please also check out my [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3bRg/).

Comment: @Deeptechtons You're free to try it in the Fiddle I have posted, but I assure you it won't work.

Comment: i actually have id in my code, i must have mistakenly put in name when i wrote the code in this question. sorry.

Comment: @Christian Then you don't have to change the `name`, just use `serialize()` the way I have shown.

Comment: @bazmegakapa also this post might help the op with getting the inputs only with value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608730/how-do-i-use-jquerys-form-serialize-but-exclude-empty-fields

Answer (score 2):

you cannot `serialize` a table -- that method doesn't apply to that kind of DOM object, only forms and form fields can be serialized.

if you really want to do what you're proposing, you need the proper selector to pick just the children of `tbl2` that are also form elements, and then you'll have to serialize each one of those by hand. someone did it in another question, here: [serialize without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371036/serialize-without-a-form)

a better way might be to disable all the form elements that are NOT in the table you're interested in -- you'll need a selector to pick all form elements that are not child elements of `tbl2` -- and THEN serialize the form. the disabled elements will be omitted.

Comment: I don't think disabling form elements would be any close to `a better way`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the serializeArray method, which will give you the array of input fields and can be used with the data.

```
var params = $("#tbl2 input").serializeArray();
```

Comment: Please note that your selector will only match `<input>` elements, and won't match other possible form elements like `<select>` or `<textarea>`.

Comment: yup its only for input as in example html, if you need additional form elements they need to be included.