# Dose bootstrap 3 form support table component?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a table inside.
When I try to get data from the form with

```
$("form").serialize()
```

I can just get data from input or select but without the table.
How can I do it?　Do I need to write another code line to get 
data from the table through table id or class?

Answer (score 0):

[serialize from a table element and not the whole form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582156/serialize-from-a-table-element-and-not-the-whole-form)
I have read the link above. And got that table cant be serialized. Setting table name attribute in the form has no effect. So I　change to use the id attribute, that works.