# dynamically added class to a table is lost when table sent using form post method

Tags: jquery, printing

I have a table which like below

```
<table id="tab" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm text-right">
      <thead class="table-header bg-light">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7"></td>
                ...
            </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
```

I added a class (i.e siz1 or size5) dynamically using jQuery. the code is below:

```
function change_size(inc_dec){
        for(i=1;i<12;i++){
            if($("#tab").hasClass("size"+i)){
                if(inc_dec==="inc"){
                    if(i != 11){
                        $("#tab").removeClass("size"+i);
                        $("#tab").addClass("size"+(i+1));
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(i != 1) {
                        $("#tab").removeClass("size" + i);
                        $("#tab").addClass("size" + (i - 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It show the changes, but when I take whole html and send it to another page using form post method to another page using the following code. I am using PHP with jQuery to send.

```
$('.export-btn').on('click',function(e){
        var html = $(this).closest('.page').find('.page-records').html();
        var title = $(this).closest('.page').find('.record-title').html();
        $('#exportformdata').val(html);
        $('#exportformtitle').val(title);
        $('#exportform').submit();
    });
```

the dynamically added class is lost .

[source code of print page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpzFt.png)

Comment: Sending HTML in a post request is a very odd thing to be doing. If you want to send some structured data to the server side, try JSON or XML instead.

Comment: this structure is built in the framework I use. I can't change unless I write a custom code to do the sending. I don't want to change the built-in functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can see below code where I am able to get the table html with updated classess.
You can click on original button first to get the html of original table html and click on update button to get the html with updated class name.

So here you need to get `html()` from parent element and not that element. You can wrap the table with some `div` as parent element.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#update").on("click", function(){
    $('table').removeClass("green");
    $('table').addClass("blue");
    var updatedHTML = $("#tab").html();
    alert(updatedHTML);
    $("#updateValue").val(updatedHTML);
  });
  $("#original").on("click", function(){
    var originalHTML = $("#tab").html();
    alert(originalHTML);
    $("#originalValue").val(originalHTML);
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab">
<table class="green">
  <tr><td>Some Test here....</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="original" id="original">
<input id="originalValue">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="update" id="update"><br>
<input id="updateValue">
```

Comment: it works on same page, but when you send to another page the dynamic class will be lost.

Comment: in this case, you can make use of jquery serialize - check this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582156/serialize-from-a-table-element-and-not-the-whole-form  and refer API document http://api.jquery.com/serialize/