# ASP.NET MVC Data Entry Multiple form tags, or just one big one?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

Looking for experienced opinions on how to deal with this:

We have a page that shows a table for user data input.  (Table haters: It's tabular data, so...)

Each input on the page is designed to "hide" a more complex form, shown via a jQuery dialog/popup.  The entire table is wrapped in a single  tag, posted when the user hits the 'submit' button at the bottom of the table.  The table rows are line items in the model.

The model passed to the controller method is basically

```
  public class MyBigModel {
    public List<LineItemModel> LineItems {get;set;}
    ...more stuff...
  }

  public class LineItemModel {
    public List<LineItemDetail> Details {get;set;}
  }

  public class LineItemDetail{
    public List<OtherDetails> SometimesIHaveDetailsToo {get;set;}
  }
```

Functionally, submitting the entire .... works fine, but we're now being asked to allow people to submit individual lines, etc.

At present, to submit single line items, I'm copying (jQuery.clone()) a table row to another form, posting that, and destroying the clone.

I've considered switching entirely to a "form per row" type of approach, but not fully sure how to deal with that--can I wrap a  with a  tag?  Should I?

Off in magic unicorn land, one might expect this sort of thing...

```
< form>
  <table>
   < form> <tr with my data and a nice submit button /> </form>
   < form> < another tr with my data and another nice submit button /> </form>
  </table>

  <input type="submit">MyMasterSubmit</input>
 </form>
```

(hoping that describes the issue well enough)

As I mentioned, the data held in each row is actually pretty complicated.  There are a number of DIV elements associated with each line item to be included as the popups, so I'm not sure they can be in a table row by themselves without causing some markup issues. It's an LOB app designed for rapid-ish data entry, so breaking it apart isn't going to be a solution.

Any ideas as to good practices to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about serializing just a div (or some 'row' surrounding tag for the selected row) and using .ajax() to the server.
[jQuery to serialize only elements within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829519/jquery-to-serialize-only-elements-within-a-div)

Comment: So in that case, I'd get the best of both worlds?  One actual <form> tag, plus "submit" each row via serialization/ajax?

Comment: yep! its simple and should work quite well. You can also hook into jQuery's ajax start and stop methods to show a nice loading image from  http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: As soon as I can get the post data formatted right, this is definitely the answer.  Thanks, Adam!