# How to override a submit button and gather form data

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a web page like this:

```
<form id="some-form">
   <input type='text'>
   <button type="submit">
</form>
. . . later in the page . . .
<div id="more-inputs">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="text">
</div>
```

For various reasons, the later inputs and check boxes can't go in the original form, but when the form is submitted, I want to use jQuery to gather the values from the checkboxes and the other forms, and submit them as a GET request.

Comment: I know this is an old, old issue, but HTML5 has a "form" attribute on many (all?) form elements that associates them with a form elsewhere on the page. There are also attributes that make the element do things differently from the form they are part of (or not part of), like "formaction", "formenctype", "formmethod", etc. I'm not sure if these would help the OP, though. He has probably moved on to other projects by now.

Comment: INDEED I HAVE NOT! I'LL LOOK INTO THIS!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this as a `GET` I'd first move the values you need up into some appended, hidden inputs into your form. Then you can call `$.get` with the `data` being a serialized version of your newly updated form.

So:

```
$('#some-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();    

  $('#more-inputs input').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $('<input type="hidden" name="' + el.attr('name') + '" />')
        .val(el.val())
        .appendTo('#some-form');
  });

  $.get('http://yoururl.com', $('#some-form').serialize(), function (data) {
      alert('handle your data here: ' + data);
  });

});
```

*Note: this requires that you have some name attributes on you inputs in 'more-inputs'*

Answer (score 7):

Just trap the `submit` `event` for your `form`?

```
$('#some-form').submit(function(){

    // do work
    // do a jquery get or whatever you need to do...
    $.get('myurl.html', function(data) {

    });

    return false; // return false to prevent typical submit behavior

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept the `submit`-event

```
$('#some-form').submit(function() {
  // your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[isNaN1247's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582465/146513) properly resolves the part about overriding the submit, but you don't actually have to move the elements into the form.

**jQuery can directly serialize those inputs inside the div**. You just need to provide a selector for getting each of those inputs (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1829952/146513)). And jQuery lets you handle both the form inputs, and the other inputs, all at once:

```
$('#some-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var requestData = $('#some-form, #more-inputs :input').serialize();

  $.get('http://yoururl.com', requestData, function (data) {
      alert('handle your data here: ' + data);
  });
});
```

Note: this answer also requires that you have some name attributes on you inputs (both in 'more-inputs' and inside the form).

You might want to test what `serialize` returns with the following code snippet:

```js
$('#some-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var requestData = $('#some-form, #more-inputs :input').serialize();
  console.log(requestData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="some-form">
   <input type='text' name="a" value="aaa">
   <input type='text' name="b" value="bbb">
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
. . . later in the page . . .
<div id="more-inputs">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checked" checked>
   <input type="text" name="d" value="ddd">
</div>
```