# post part of form using jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

im trying to post a table which is a part of bigger form using jquery

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input name=name[] value='sam' type='hidden' />Sam</td>
<td><input name=age[] value='16' type='hidden' />16</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input name=name[] value='jesse' type='hidden' />Jesse</td>
<td><input name=age[] value='15' type='hidden' />15</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

im trying to post this table using jquery

```
$('#Sx_apply').click(function(){
    var vals={};
    $('table').find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){vals.push($(this).val());})
    $('<div>').load($(this).data('apply'),vals);
});
```

but my question is how to push key=input name with the input value.

i tried `vals[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();` but since all tr's have same name (array post) they overwrite each others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829519/jquery-to-serialize-only-elements-within-a-div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('#Sx_apply').click(function(){
    var vals = $('table :input').serialize();
    $('<div>').load($(this).data('apply'),vals);
});
```

Comment: NO, You can use it like that also.

Comment: wow it worked :) ! i dont know why i thought that .seriailize and .serializeArray only take a #form as selector ! but i tried it and it worked thanks :)