# can not get a form by its id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that created in an external file and then i'm including it by php and then getting this form by its id to serialize.
index.php

```
<div id="addressesList">        
 <?php include 'addresstable.php' ?>
</div>
```

view source of index.php file:
[image]

jquery code in index.php:

```
<script>
   function editAddress(){
       $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#addressListForm').serialize() , // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true; + '&' + 'editAddress' + '=' + id
        success: function (result) {
          //$(thisObj).parents("tr:first").remove();

          $("#addressesList").html(result);
        }
    }); 
   }
</script>
```

I want to get the form that its id is "addressListForm" by click on an element that calls editAdress function.
addresstable.php file

```
                <?php
                    $i=1;
                    $results=mysqli_query($dbCnn,"select * from addresses");
                    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

                    { 
                        echo '<form action="insert.php" method="post" id="addressListForm">';
                        echo "<tr>
                                <input type='hidden' value='$row[id]' name='id'/> 
                                <td>$i</td>
                                <td><input name='title' type='text' value='$row[title]' style='width:60px'  /></td>
                                <td><input name='address' type='text' value='$row[address]' style='width:100%' /></td>
                                <td><input name='tel' type='text' value='$row[phone]' required='required' style='width:100px' /></td> 
                                <td><input name='fax' type='text' value='$row[fax]' required='required' style='width:100px' /></td>
                                <td><i onclick=\"editAddress($row[id],this)\" class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='ثبت تغییرات رایانامه'></i></td> 
                                <td><i onclick=\"deleteAddress($row[id],this)\" class='fa fa-trash-o deletUser' title='حذف کاربر' ></i></td>
                            </tr>";

                    $i++;
                    echo"</form>";
                }
            ?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: You want to load the form from another location when you click in your current page?

Comment: And where do you serialize your form data?

Comment: You cannot embed form element inside a tbody. That's invalid and not supported

Comment: where did `id` get defined? you call the function with two arguments, but the function definition shows **NO** arguments.

Comment: <?php include 'addresstable.php' ?>

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: @Webinan but  i need  to create multiple form by while(php) for each row

Comment: check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

In the `addresstable.php` file you should put the table tag inside the form, the `addressListForm` id is now unreachable (it's obvious in the syntax highlighting of source too).

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form ...></form>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <form ...></form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

if you have multiple forms put each one in a new `<tr><td>` , `</td></tr>`

change it to:

```
                <?php
                    $i=1;
                    $results=mysqli_query($dbCnn,"select * from addresses");
                    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

                    { 
                        echo "<tr id="addressListForm">

                                       <td>
                                        <input type='hidden' value='$row[id]' name='id'/> 
                                       $i</td>
                                       <td><input name='title' type='text' value='$row[title]' style='width:60px'  /></td>
                                       <td><input name='address' type='text' value='$row[address]' style='width:100%' /></td>
                                       <td><input name='tel' type='text' value='$row[phone]' required='required' style='width:100px' /></td> 
                                       <td><input name='fax' type='text' value='$row[fax]' required='required' style='width:100px' /></td>
                                       <td><i onclick=\"editAddress($row[id],this)\" class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='ثبت تغییرات رایانامه'></i></td> 
                                       <td><i onclick=\"deleteAddress($row[id],this)\" class='fa fa-trash-o deletUser' title='حذف کاربر' ></i></td>

                             </tr>";

                    $i++;
                }
            ?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: I have edited the question again. pay attention to addresstable.php

Comment: thanks, it works,but i'm usin slimtable to paging and sort the table and you code make some problems for it

Comment: @Hamid edited again, since your using serilize and ajax to get and send data, you don't need a `<form>` tag so I deleted it, and see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1829952/2543240

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by changing somethings in my codes:

index.php

```
    function editAddress(id,thisObj,x){
        var formId="#addressListForm" + x;
       $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(formId).serialize()+ '&' + 'editAddress' + '=' + id , 
        success: function (result) {
         $("#addressesList").html(result);

        }
    }); 
   }
```

and addresstable.php file

```
    <tbody id="addressTb">

        <?php
                $i=1;
                $results=mysqli_query($dbCnn,"select * from addresses");
                while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

                { 
                    echo "
                              <tr>
                                   <td>$i<form action='insert.php' method='post' id='addressListForm$i'><input form='addressListForm$i' type='hidden' value='$row[id]' name='id'/> </td>
                                   <td><input form='addressListForm$i' name='title' type='text' value='$row[title]' style='width:60px'  /></td>
                                   <td><input form='addressListForm$i' name='address' type='text' value='$row[address]' style='width:100%' /></td>
                                   <td><input form='addressListForm$i' name='phone' type='text' value='$row[phone]' required='required' style='width:100px' /></td> 
                                   <td><input form='addressListForm$i' name='fax' type='text' value='$row[fax]' required='required' style='width:100px' /></td>
                                   <td><i onclick=\"editAddress($row[id],this,$i)\" class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='ثبت تغییرات رایانامه'></i></td>
                                   <td><i onclick=\"deleteAddress($row[id],this,$i)\" class='fa fa-trash-o deletUser' title='حذف کاربر' ></i></form></td> 
                                 </tr>
                         ";
                $i++;
            }
        ?>       
</tbody>
```

Comment: this is an invalid markup, tags should not have conflicts `<td> <from> </td> </form>`

Comment: it's working very well, with no error and warning in source view