# is there any way to get form elements and its related values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a `div`

```
<div id="ip"> 
   <input type="text" name="first" value="cobra" class="mark1"/>
   <input type="text" name="second" value="python" class="mark2"/>
</div>
```

i'm serialising it like this,

```
$('div#ip:input').serialize();
```

if i do `serialization` of the above `div` i will get only value's but i want `element` also,  is there any good way to do that or i have to store the whole `html` `element`  into my `database`   like above `div` , in reality it is going to be huge.

**my question:**  what is the best way to store `html element` into `database` like above `div`  with its all `values,names,classes fields` must be intact.

i'm using `php` in server side.

**last question:** storing `html element` is the only way?

Comment: you need to add `form` not just `div` and then you can use like `$('#FormId).serialize();`

Comment: first why do you need the html input fields in your db?

Comment: Why do you want the element? By element, do you mean the `<input>`? (Just so we're clear we're talking about the same thing)

Comment: If you have big heart you can create a table for `html elements` and one for their `properties and values`.

Comment: i'm refering this thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829519/jquery-to-serialize-only-elements-within-a-div

Comment: i'm developing `CMS` where `element` need to be `dragged` and `drop`  so i want to know any way is there

Comment: @DilipG you should give each element a unique identifier and save the resulting array not the html, you can then rearrange the elements based on that array

Comment: @madalinivascu, can you just give me an idea of that

Comment: @DilipG you will need some ajax 1.for saving the position of the input files, 2. to rearrange the input files after the save , its a bit complicate

Comment: @madalinivascu, refering this thread i can iterate over each `element` and store them into `object`, what i'm not getting here is how to `store` `class` name into `object`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Comment: @DilipG let me edit my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a loop to get each input class value and name, after that you do a ajax call to your server and save the data to the db:

```
var data =[];
$('input,textarea,select').each(function(){
     data.push({
       class:$(this).attr('class'),
       name:$(this).attr('name'),
       value:$(this).val();
     });
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: im using `formbuilder.js` it is a `drag` and `drop` for `elements` so  i'm asking this question

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to get the serialized HTML fragment.

Then use `toString()` to convert it to string. Later you can save this string in the database. It will save the value along with the  tag.

```
 var a = (document.getElementById("ip").outerHTML);
 a.toString();// convert to string. Save this string in database
```

Later use jquery `parseHTML` to convert this string to html and redraw the dom

```
// demodiv is a placeholder to convert string to html and repaint the dom
$("#demoDiv").append($.parseHTML(a)) // a is the value retrieved from db
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/npc3fapo/)

Comment: i know this is a solution, is it a optmal way to store very big `string` into `database` ???

Comment: @DilipG seems it is a db related question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
$("#ip").clone().html()
```