# serialize inputs inside element (not form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

I have a HTML like:

```
<table>
    <tr id="01">
        <td><input name="x"></td>
        <td><input name="y"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="02">
        <td><input name="x"></td>
        <td><input name="y"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I'm trying to make a JSON string of the inputs only on a specific row. Would there be a good solution for this? Something like:

```
json = $('#01').serialize();
```

but I need a json instead of the URLEncode'd string the serialize() provides.

Comment: Wrap them in a useless form

Comment: Try `$("#01 input").serialize`?!

Comment: @bassxzero You can't put a form inside a `<tr>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery to serialize only elements within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829519/jquery-to-serialize-only-elements-within-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serialize() won't give you the JSON you're after. It'll only give you a URLEncode'd string. Example:

```js
//test all inputs on row #02
window.tester = function() { 
 console.log($('#02 input').serialize());
};

//test all inputs
window.tester2 = function() { 
 console.log($('input').serialize());
};

//test only "y" inputs
window.tester3 = function() { 
 console.log($("input[name='y']").serialize());
};
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="01">
        <td><input name="x" value="1"></td>
        <td><input name="y" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="02">
        <td><input name="x" value="3"></td>
        <td><input name="y" value="4"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
  <input type="button" onclick="tester()" value="Test Row 02" /><br />
  <input type="button" onclick="tester2()" value="Test All Inputs" /><br />
  <input type="button" onclick="tester3()" value="Test Only 'y' Inputs" />
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Produces:

```
x=3&y=4
x=1&y=2&x=3&y=4
y=2&y=4
```

If it's JSON you want, then you'll need to be specific about what format you're after. An array? A hash? In any case, the selectors above are what you'll want to start with, then at some point, you'll want to run the value through:

```
JSON.stringify(myResults);
```

```js
window.arrayIt = function () {
  var arrVal = $('#02 input').toArray();
  var arr = arrVal.map(function (i) {
    var x = {};
    x[i.name] = i.value;
    return x;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="01">
        <td><input name="x" value="1"></td>
        <td><input name="y" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="02">
        <td><input name="x" value="3"></td>
        <td><input name="y" value="4"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="arrayIt()">Array It!</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I know my real problem was not knowing a decent way to turn the inputs of a specific tr tag into an array. That function basically solves my problem, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `$("#01 input").serialize()`.

```js
$('#abc').click(function(){
    json = $("#01 input").serialize().replace(/%20/g, "+");
    console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="01">
        <td><input name="x"></td>
        <td><input name="y"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="02">
        <td><input name="x"></td>
        <td><input name="y"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id = "abc">serialize 01</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.serialize()` can be used on a collection of inputs.

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var data = $("#01 input").serialize();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="01">
    <td><input name="x"></td>
    <td><input name="y"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="02">
    <td><input name="x"></td>
    <td><input name="y"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">Click</button>
```

BTW, the result of `serialize()` isn't JSON, it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.